# Getting element values in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I spent lots of time trying to figure out getting a values from an element using jquery. Here's the code

```html
<div class="school">
    <div class="school-prev">
        <img src="images/photos.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <h5 class="school-title">Admin</h5>
    <small class="text-muted">School Board</small>
</div>

<div class="school">
    <div class="school-prev">
        <img src="images/photos2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <h5 class="school-title">Finance</h5>
    <small class="text-muted">School Board</small>
</div>
```

Jquery Coe

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".school").click('.school-title', function(e){
        var showValue=$(this).text();
        alert(showValue);
    }); 
});
```

Example of return values: Admin School Board;

Expected value is should be "Admin or Finance"

NB: Any solution should consider outside div(school) clickable and not school-title div alone.

Warm regards.

Comment: Try `$(this).find(".school-title").text();` instead of `$(this).text()`. Demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/WNwQLwE

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `jQuery` code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  // console.log('th');
  $(document).on('click','.school .school-title', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var th = $(this); //change over here
        console.log(th.text());
    }); 
});
```

Comment: First why would this work? second now you have an undeclared variable called showValue

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can change `$(".school").click('.school-title', function(e){` to `$(".school").on('click', '.school-title', function(e) {` and it will solve the problem for you.

After updating your NB, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".school").click(function(e) {
    var showValue = $('.school-title',this).text()
    alert(showValue);
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".school").click(function(e) {
    var showValue = $('.school-title',this).text()
    alert(showValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="school">
  <div class="school-prev">
    <img src="images/photos.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
  </div>
  <h5 class="school-title">Admin</h5>
  <small class="text-muted">School Board</small>
</div>

<div class="school">
  <div class="school-prev">
    <img src="images/photos2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
  </div>
  <h5 class="school-title">Finance</h5>
  <small class="text-muted">School Board</small>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work when you click in the `school` div though - it only works when you click on the title itself.

Comment: Actually, that requirement was there from the very beginning... :)

Answer (score 0):

You want a click *anywhere* in the `school` div to get the title - not just on the title itself. To do that, you just need to check for the `school-title` child element in the click function on `school`.

This will get all children with the class `school-title` (of which there will only be one - it works the same as `find` except on direct children only) and get the text from it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".school").click('.school-title', function(e){
    var showValue=$(this).children('.school-title').text();
      alert(showValue);
    }); 
});
```

```css
/* Just for illustration  to make it easier to see what is happening */
.school { border: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="school">
<div class="school-prev">
<img src="images/photos.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
</div>
<h5 class="school-title">Admin</h5>
<small class="text-muted">School Board</small>
</div>

<div class="school">
<div class="school-prev">
<img src="images/photos2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
</div>
<h5 class="school-title">Finance</h5>
<small class="text-muted">School Board</small>
</div>
```

You only have one child with `school-title` in this case, but it will work with multiple titles if needed (e.g. if you did want to get "Admin School Board" for example, you could simply add the `school-title` class to the `text-muted` element).

Reference: [jQuery `children` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? This was actually the first answer to get the requirements right... I even had to let other users know to correct theirs :)

Comment: not sure who down voted a working answer. but plus 1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'school' class name for the click event and want to get the value child element of div. That is not possible in this way.
Simply Change the code "$(this).text();" to "$(classname,this).text();".
Happy coding.

Comment: if he changed it to `$('classname').text();"` like `$('.school-title').text();"` it would not have a dynamic relation to the clicked element

Comment: Yeah! Sorry, You are right @CarstenLøvboAndersen . This would not work. Updated Now.